# IOS, how to handle multiple local notifications when app start?

Tags: ios, nstimer, uilocalnotification

I'm creating an app that uses timers. 
Let's say that the user can set multiple timers; for each of those timers the app schedule a local notification. When the app is running in foreground or  is in background i have no problem handling multiple local notifications.
my problem is when the user set multiple timers and **then terminate the app**( double click on home button and close the app). in that case, when timers expire all relative local notifications are shown as a banner and the app icon badge is incremented. so i want to handle all of those notifications when the user start the app from notification banner or tapping on app icon  but using

> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

I am able to handle only one notification with

> [launchOptions UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]

I need to handle all local notifications of all timers!! how can i do that?

Comment: Hi please share if any solution found...even i want to achieve this...but no solution found yet...

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to each local notification so you know from which notification was the app triggered:

```
localNotification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; 
localNotification1.userInfo = @{ "type" : @1 };
...
localNotification2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; 
localNotification2.userInfo = @{ "type" : @2 };
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/userInfo

Comment: thanks.perhaps I have not explained well my problem. Let's say the user set 2 timers in the app. Then before timers expire, the user terminate the app(not in background). after that, when the first timer is expired, the banner of first notification is shown.let's say the user ignore this one. then the second timer expire and the relative notification is shown(always with the app closed).now the user tap on this second notification and the app start. I want to show an alert for all those timers when app start,but with `launchOptions` i can show an alert for only one

Comment: If the app is not running in the background there is very high chance that the local notifications won't trigger. You should consider using push notifications for what you wante.

Comment: Should i consider push notifications for notify events on the same device? i thought push notifications are relative to client-server app.

Comment: Push notifications assure you that even if the app is not opened, they will be delivered to the device and can be handled in the same way as localnotifications.