# iOS : Handle multiple uilocalnotification with multiple same viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uilocalnotification

I am using UILocalnotification...on receiving the notification i open viewcontroller when the app is in active mode...but if multiple notifications are received at same time...how do i open the multiple viewcontroller...above each other and dismiss them sequentially....I tried opening viewcontroller but receiving this error

```
Warning: Attempt to present <NotificationViewController: 0x7fc033b43900> on <UINavigationController: 0x7fc031859600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hack to do this.

write an extension to view controller:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var lastPresentedViewController: UIViewController {
        guard let presentedViewController = presentedViewController else { return self }
        return presentedViewController.lastPresentedViewController()
    }
}
```

or objc:

UIViewController+LastPresentedViewController.h:

```
@interface UIViewController (LastPresentedViewController)
-(UIViewController *)lastPresentedViewController;
@end
```

UIViewController+LastPresentedViewController.m:

```
@implementation UIViewController (LastPresentedViewController)
- (UIViewController *)lastPresentedViewController {
    if (self.presentedViewController) {
        return [self.presentedViewController lastPresentedViewController];
    } else {
        return self;
    }
}
@end
```

when you need to present a view controller from navigationController just call this method like this:

```
navigationController.lastPresentedViewController.presentViewController(....
```

if you are already inside navigationController just call `lastPresentedViewController.presentViewController(...`

Comment: hmm I haven't written objective-c for a long time let me try :)

Comment: I guess you can figure out how to call it?

Comment: it worked awesome thanks...one more query...[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677471/ios-how-to-handle-multiple-local-notifications-when-app-start#comment29225363_19677566)

Comment: any idea about how to acknowledge other uilocalnotification as well when i click on one notification??

Comment: you can store the old one or ones maybe